# Post as a guest breaks Responsive Layout

Tags: bug, design

Steps to reproduce:

1. Logout of SO (might be hard, I would advise you to open a Incognito Window)
2. Find a question on SO
3. Make the width of the screen small (like 400px)
4. Notice you can scroll to the right

Using [Ghost CSS](http://wernull.com/2013/04/debug-ghost-css-elements-causing-unwanted-scrolling/) showed this beauty:

[image: Windows 10 Enterprise v.1803, Google Chrome v68.0.3440.75]
*Windows 10 Enterprise v.1803, Google Chrome v68.0.3440.75*

[image: MacOS X El Capitan v10.11.6, Google Chrome v67.0.3396.99]
*MacOS X El Capitan v10.11.6, Google Chrome v67.0.3396.99*

Comment: Reproducible on Nightly 63.0a1. The `div.new-login-form` has a fixed width of `670px`, but it seems to work just fine without that (without testing thoroughly).

Comment: That is a neat trick, actually. I never thought to debug CSS problems by making the site look excruciatingly garish.

Comment: It definitely helps to find what is breaking the layout

Comment: [question on the over-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) lists a supported browser window width of 1032px.

Comment: Hmm, actually good point yeah. But isn't the point of responsive design made so it works on all devices? That source is from 2016, and that was added on Dec. 2017 (Revision 92). The new layout was announced ~March https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/384057
Probably would be needed more clarification on this case

Comment: Checked the website on mobile, and its a completely different layout. I'm actually confused

Comment: @André Why are you confused?  Most websites serve an utterly different webpage to mobile users.  You can even toggle back to the real webpage on mobile (link is at bottom of page, called [full site]) or make non-mobile browsers see mobile version (link is also down there, called [Mobile]).

Comment: @TZHX The source on that is pre-responsive layout. The responsive layout includes specific rules for screens 790px wide and smaller, so that's no longer up-to-date.